# Scroll to bottom of table using jScrollPane with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I use [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html) in my asp.net winforms application

I have one table, is inside the scrollpane,

I want to set with JQuery or JavaScript scroll to bottom, in line with last tr from table

You have some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scrollPane has scrollToBottom function:

```
var scrollPane = $('tableSelector').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
scrollPane.scrollToBottom();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

If you don't know what the height is of your table (Dynamic?):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yourtable');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

If you do know the height:

```
document.getElementById('yourtable').scrollTop = yourvalueinpixels;
```

I hope this helps!